# Truffle Migrate Error: The network id specified in the truffle config (5777) does not match the one returned by the network (1)

Tags: truffle-migration, error

I'm a bit new here and I've been trying to migrate truffle however I keep running into this error:
Error: The network id specified in the truffle config (5777) does not match the one returned by the network (1).  Ensure that both the network and the provider are properly configured.

I've tried to specify the network in truffle-config.js file although that hasn't worked. It currently looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  },
}
```

Trying to run ganache forked and haven't been able to change networkId from 1. Cannot for the life of me find the issue, any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: How do you run ganache?

Comment: I've been running it through terminal with command: ganache -f -m <Mnemonic phrase> -u <user> -p 7545

Answer (score 0):

Try running ganache with:

`--networkId 5777`

Comment: `Unknown argument: chainId` is returned.

Comment: @Madds edited, I wrote to ganache-cli

Comment: Even running ganache with `--networkId 5777` I get a Network ID: 1 returned on the forked chain.